# Parsing "shell friendly" output

Tags: bash, variable, xdotool

I would like to get output from

```
xdotool getactivewindow getwindowgeometry --shell
```

to local variables in bash.

Thought I might could do something like:

```
declare -A wp=( $(xdotool getactivewindow getwindowgeometry --shell | \
sed 's/\(^[^=]*\)/[\1]/') )

# sub gives:

# [WINDOW]=48926121
# [X]=366
# [Y]=96
# [WIDTH]=819
# [HEIGHT]=1022
# [SCREEN]=0
```

But this fails with

> must use subscript when assigning associative array

another way is to declare local all known values of output and use `eval`. A safer is to grep, sed or the like six times for each of the values.

Both of these seems very wonky. Is there a better way? Some way to do it in one swoop?

Comment: What do you mean by local variables?  They only exist inside functions.  What do you mean by "sub gives"?  Is that the output of your command?

Comment: Oh, I see, you want to load `xdotool --shell` output into an associative array instead of just eval'ing it flat as described in the manpage.

Comment: It works the way you wrote but you still need eval for the subscript to be treated as such.

Comment: related: [JSON array to bash variables using jq](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/413878/json-array-to-bash-variables-using-jq)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a loop-based solution is acceptable, then you could do

```
declare -A wp
while IFS='=' read -r name value; do 
  wp+=([$name]=$value)
done < <(xdotool getactivewindow getwindowgeometry --shell)
```

Ex.

```
$ declare -A wp
$ while IFS='=' read -r name value; do 
    wp+=([$name]=$value)
  done < <(xdotool getactivewindow getwindowgeometry --shell)

$ for name in "${!wp[@]}"; do 
    printf 'Value of %s is %s\n' "$name" "${wp[$name]}"
  done
Value of WINDOW is 81788935
Value of WIDTH is 1440
Value of SCREEN is 0
Value of X is 0
Value of HEIGHT is 866
Value of Y is 34
```

Comment: `wp["$name"]="$value"` also works.  i.e. += isn't required.