# JSON with jq into bash array / loop through

Tags: bash, jq

I have a JSON result which I want to go through and send an alert, if one or several of the values in the JSON string is smashing thresholds.

This bash command:

`` for sat in `docker exec -i storagenode wget -qO - localhost:14002/api/sno | jq .satellites[].id -r`; do docker exec -i storagenode wget -qO - localhost:14002/api/sno/satellite/$sat | jq .id,.audits; done ``

Provides the following (excerpt):

```
"12tRQrMTWUWwzwGh18i7Fqs67kmdhH9t6aToeiwbo5mfS2rUmo"
{
  "auditScore": 1,
  "suspensionScore": 1,
  "onlineScore": 0.9974358974358974,
  "satelliteName": "us2.storj.io:7777"
}
"1wFTAgs9DP5RSnCqKV1eLf6N9wtk4EAtmN5DpSxcs8EjT69tGE"
{
  "auditScore": 1,
  "suspensionScore": 1,
  "onlineScore": 0.9989041005632043,
  "satelliteName": "saltlake.tardigrade.io:7777"
}
```

Now I want to go through the results and e.g. in case, onlineScore drops below 0.9 (or suspensionScore resp. auditScore below 1.0, I want to create a text alert, which also includes the satelliteName. Example: `auditScore below threshold: 0.98 for us2.storj.io`

I guess I can start with the following (from [JSON array to bash variables using jq](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/413878/json-array-to-bash-variables-using-jq)), but I do not know, how to loop through the results and how to name and validate the fields:

```
jq -r '.[] | to_entries | .[] | .key + "=" + (.value | @sh)'
```

**UPDATE #1**

```bsh
docker exec -i storagenode wget -qO - localhost:14002/api/sno
```

provides:

```
{"nodeID":"1veqEG5xuBNkt...","wallet":"12345","walletFeatures":["zksync"],"satellites":[{"id":"12tRQrMTWUWwzwGh18i7Fqs67kmdhH9t6aToeiwbo5mfS2rUmo","url":"us2.storj.io:7777","disqualified":null,"suspended":null,"currentStorageUsed":4592556672},{"id":"1wFTAgs9DP5RSnCqKV1eLf6N9wtk4EAtmN5DpSxcs8EjT69tGE","url":"saltlake.tardigrade.io:7777","disqualified":null,"suspended":null,"currentStorageUsed":513269323264},{"id":"121RTSDpyNZVcEU84Ticf2L1ntiuUimbWgfATz21tuvgk3vzoA6","url":"ap1.storj.io:7777","disqualified":null,"suspended":null,"currentStorageUsed":70956116864},{"id":"12EayRS2V1kEsWESU9QMRseFhdxYxKicsiFmxrsLZHeLUtdps3S","url":"us1.storj.io:7777","disqualified":null,"suspended":null,"currentStorageUsed":322340591104},{"id":"12L9ZFwhzVpuEKMUNUqkaTLGzwY9G24tbiigLiXpmZWKwmcNDDs","url":"eu1.storj.io:7777","disqualified":null,"suspended":null,"currentStorageUsed":148740125312},{"id":"12rfG3sh9NCWiX3ivPjq2HtdLmbqCrvHVEzJubnzFzosMuawymB","url":"europe-north-1.tardigrade.io:7777","disqualified":null,"suspended":null,"currentStorageUsed":100681406976}],"diskSpace":{"used":1162257094528,"available":9500000000000,"trash":43196690332,"overused":0},"bandwidth":{"used":31670206976,"available":0},"lastPinged":"2022-01-02T07:55:51.886776586Z","version":"1.45.3","allowedVersion":"1.24.0","upToDate":true,"startedAt":"2021-12-31T00:00:32.209840775Z"}
```

And this one:

```bsh
docker exec -i storagenode wget -qO - localhost:14002/api/sno/satellite/1wFTAgs9DP5RSnCqKV1eLf6N9wtk4EAtmN5DpSxcs8EjT69tGE
```

provides:

```
{"id":"1wFTAgs9DP5RSnCqKV1eLf6N9wtk4EAtmN5DpSxcs8EjT69tGE","storageDaily":[{"atRestTotal":11726579066524.266,"intervalStart":"2022-01-01T00:00:00Z"}],"bandwidthDaily":[{"egress":{"repair":390576640,"audit":7424,"usage":2373615872},"ingress":{"repair":2745100032,"usage":26744320},"delete":0,"intervalStart":"2022-01-01T00:00:00Z"},{"egress":{"repair":143168256,"audit":3584,"usage":786989568},"ingress":{"repair":1034401280,"usage":8107264},"delete":0,"intervalStart":"2022-01-02T00:00:00Z"}],"storageSummary":11726579066524.266,"bandwidthSummary":7508714240,"egressSummary":3694361344,"ingressSummary":3814352896,"currentStorageUsed":513269323264,"audits":{"auditScore":1,"suspensionScore":1,"onlineScore":0.9989041005632043,"satelliteName":"saltlake.tardigrade.io:7777"},"auditHistory":{"score":0.9989041005632043,"windows":[{"windowStart":"2021-12-03T00:00:00Z","totalCount":36,"onlineCount":36},{"windowStart":"2021-12-03T12:00:00Z","totalCount":30,"onlineCount":30},{"windowStart":"2021-12-04T00:00:00Z","totalCount":43,"onlineCount":42},{"windowStart":"2021-12-04T12:00:00Z","totalCount":68,"onlineCount":68},{"windowStart":"2021-12-05T00:00:00Z","totalCount":53,"onlineCount":53},{"windowStart":"2021-12-05T12:00:00Z","totalCount":36,"onlineCount":36},{"windowStart":"2021-12-06T00:00:00Z","totalCount":33,"onlineCount":33},{"windowStart":"2021-12-06T12:00:00Z","totalCount":53,"onlineCount":53},{"windowStart":"2021-12-07T00:00:00Z","totalCount":27,"onlineCount":27},{"windowStart":"2021-12-07T12:00:00Z","totalCount":65,"onlineCount":65},{"windowStart":"2021-12-08T00:00:00Z","totalCount":30,"onlineCount":30},{"windowStart":"2021-12-08T12:00:00Z","totalCount":27,"onlineCount":27},{"windowStart":"2021-12-09T00:00:00Z","totalCount":46,"onlineCount":46},{"windowStart":"2021-12-09T12:00:00Z","totalCount":48,"onlineCount":48},{"windowStart":"2021-12-10T00:00:00Z","totalCount":49,"onlineCount":49},{"windowStart":"2021-12-10T12:00:00Z","totalCount":67,"onlineCount":67},{"windowStart":"2021-12-11T00:00:00Z","totalCount":71,"onlineCount":71},{"windowStart":"2021-12-11T12:00:00Z","totalCount":52,"onlineCount":52},{"windowStart":"2021-12-12T00:00:00Z","totalCount":59,"onlineCount":59},{"windowStart":"2021-12-12T12:00:00Z","totalCount":77,"onlineCount":77},{"windowStart":"2021-12-13T00:00:00Z","totalCount":79,"onlineCount":79},{"windowStart":"2021-12-13T12:00:00Z","totalCount":79,"onlineCount":79},{"windowStart":"2021-12-14T00:00:00Z","totalCount":65,"onlineCount":65},{"windowStart":"2021-12-14T12:00:00Z","totalCount":59,"onlineCount":59},{"windowStart":"2021-12-15T00:00:00Z","totalCount":87,"onlineCount":87},{"windowStart":"2021-12-15T12:00:00Z","totalCount":82,"onlineCount":81},{"windowStart":"2021-12-16T00:00:00Z","totalCount":96,"onlineCount":96},{"windowStart":"2021-12-16T12:00:00Z","totalCount":66,"onlineCount":64},{"windowStart":"2021-12-17T00:00:00Z","totalCount":36,"onlineCount":36},{"windowStart":"2021-12-17T12:00:00Z","totalCount":48,"onlineCount":48},{"windowStart":"2021-12-18T00:00:00Z","totalCount":37,"onlineCount":37},{"windowStart":"2021-12-18T12:00:00Z","totalCount":60,"onlineCount":60},{"windowStart":"2021-12-19T00:00:00Z","totalCount":69,"onlineCount":69},{"windowStart":"2021-12-19T12:00:00Z","totalCount":32,"onlineCount":32},{"windowStart":"2021-12-20T00:00:00Z","totalCount":53,"onlineCount":53},{"windowStart":"2021-12-20T12:00:00Z","totalCount":37,"onlineCount":37},{"windowStart":"2021-12-21T00:00:00Z","totalCount":80,"onlineCount":80},{"windowStart":"2021-12-21T12:00:00Z","totalCount":57,"onlineCount":57},{"windowStart":"2021-12-22T00:00:00Z","totalCount":46,"onlineCount":46},{"windowStart":"2021-12-22T12:00:00Z","totalCount":33,"onlineCount":33},{"windowStart":"2021-12-23T00:00:00Z","totalCount":42,"onlineCount":42},{"windowStart":"2021-12-23T12:00:00Z","totalCount":73,"onlineCount":73},{"windowStart":"2021-12-24T00:00:00Z","totalCount":35,"onlineCount":35},{"windowStart":"2021-12-24T12:00:00Z","totalCount":44,"onlineCount":44},{"windowStart":"2021-12-25T00:00:00Z","totalCount":81,"onlineCount":81},{"windowStart":"2021-12-25T12:00:00Z","totalCount":43,"onlineCount":43},{"windowStart":"2021-12-26T00:00:00Z","totalCount":62,"onlineCount":62},{"windowStart":"2021-12-26T12:00:00Z","totalCount":79,"onlineCount":79},{"windowStart":"2021-12-27T00:00:00Z","totalCount":70,"onlineCount":70},{"windowStart":"2021-12-27T12:00:00Z","totalCount":90,"onlineCount":90},{"windowStart":"2021-12-28T00:00:00Z","totalCount":65,"onlineCount":65},{"windowStart":"2021-12-28T12:00:00Z","totalCount":77,"onlineCount":77},{"windowStart":"2021-12-29T00:00:00Z","totalCount":83,"onlineCount":83},{"windowStart":"2021-12-29T12:00:00Z","totalCount":99,"onlineCount":99},{"windowStart":"2021-12-30T00:00:00Z","totalCount":74,"onlineCount":74},{"windowStart":"2021-12-30T12:00:00Z","totalCount":84,"onlineCount":84},{"windowStart":"2021-12-31T00:00:00Z","totalCount":70,"onlineCount":70},{"windowStart":"2021-12-31T12:00:00Z","totalCount":93,"onlineCount":93},{"windowStart":"2022-01-01T00:00:00Z","totalCount":120,"onlineCount":120},{"windowStart":"2022-01-01T12:00:00Z","totalCount":112,"onlineCount":112},{"windowStart":"2022-01-02T00:00:00Z","totalCount":46,"onlineCount":46}]},"priceModel":{"EgressBandwidth":2000,"RepairBandwidth":1000,"AuditBandwidth":1000,"DiskSpace":150},"nodeJoinedAt":"2021-05-11T20:11:14.910165Z"}
```

Sorry, not sure how to better format the huge json content here in a better way.

**UPDATE #2**

There is a result for `http://localhost:14002/api/sno/satellites`, I was not aware of before. The result is:

```json
{
...
   "storageSummary": 6.8624392E13,
...
   "audits": [
      {
         "auditScore": 1,
         "suspensionScore": 1,
         "onlineScore": 0.99743587,
         "satelliteName": "us2.storj.io:7777"
      },
      {
         "auditScore": 1,
         "suspensionScore": 1,
         "onlineScore": 0.9992917,
         "satelliteName": "saltlake.tardigrade.io:7777"
      },
...
      {
         "auditScore": 1,
         "suspensionScore": 1,
         "onlineScore": 0.99930555,
         "satelliteName": "ap1.storj.io:7777"
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Your sample JSON isn't well-formed, which makes it difficult to make a concrete suggestion.  Can you update the example and make it look like what you'd really expect to see?

Comment: This Q belongs rather to programming than U&L

Comment: I felt inspired coz there are other questions here about the same topic, with other example JSON. Hmm

Comment: Andy, yes, from what I can see from the select, it’s possible to restructure: ```for sat in `docker exec -i storagenode wget -qO - localhost:14002/api/sno | jq .satellites[].id -r`; do docker exec -i storagenode wget -qO - localhost:14002/api/sno/satellite/$sat | jq .id,.audits; done```

Comment: You most recent comment refers to keys `id` and `audit` which is not part of the JSON document structure that you are showing in your question. Consider updating your data so that it corresponds to the data that you are actually working with. The thing you want to do is _trivial_ with `jq`, but _very difficult_ to help you with when you only show snippets of selected pieces data.

Comment: I’ve updated the description above. Hope it helps.

Comment: Do you have `jq` available inside the Docker container, or could you arrange with having it available? In that case you don't have to run any part of the solution outside of the container. This would make it a fair bit easier to write a robust script.

Comment: Does the REST API that you are using allow for queries containing multiple IDs? That would speed things up considerably. Is the documentation for the REST endpoints available publicly?

Comment: Uh, don’t know. I can ask this question to the storj community, where the API is from. Will keep you posted.

Comment: Btw which ids in concrete? Satellite ids in the first docker statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's generally a good idea to avoid looping over the result of a command substitution. It's inelegant as the command in the substitution must finish executing before the loop can even start running, it's inefficient as the full result of the command in the substitution must be stored in memory, and it's prone to errors since the shell must be allowed to split the output of the command on whitespace and subject the resulting words to filename globbing.

It's better to use `read` in a `while` loop:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

curl -s 'localhost:14002/api/sno' |
jq -r '.satellites[].id' |
while IFS= read -r id; do
        curl -s 'localhost:14002/api/sno/satellite/'"$id"
done |
jq -r \
        --argjson auditScore 1 \
        --argjson suspensionScore 1 \
        --argjson onlineScore 0.9 \
        '.audits as $a | $a.satelliteName as $name |
        reduce ($ARGS.named|keys[]) as $key (
                [];
                if $a[$key] < $ARGS.named[$key] then (
                        . + ["\($key) below threshold: \($a[$key]) for \($name)"]
                ) else . end
        ) | .[]'
```

This script assumes that you can contact your REST endpoints on `localhost:14002` (the Docker container might be made to expose that port, for example).  If you need to use the `docker exec` command to access the API, then replace the plain calls to `curl` with, e.g.

```bsh
docker exec -i curl -s 'localhost:14002/api/sno'
```

---

For the updated question, using the `api/sno/satellites` endpoint:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

curl -s 'localhost:14002/api/sno/satellites' |
jq -r \
        --argjson auditScore 1 \
        --argjson suspensionScore 1 \
        --argjson onlineScore 0.9 \
        '.audits[] as $a | $a.satelliteName as $name |
        reduce ($ARGS.named|keys[]) as $key (
                [];
                if $a[$key] < $ARGS.named[$key] then (
                        . + ["\($key) below threshold: \($a[$key]) for \($name)"]
                ) else . end
        ) | .[]'
```

Apart from a minor adjustment to the `jq` expression, this is essentially the same code as above, but bypassing the first `curl` call to fetch all the IDs, and the loop.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I gave it a try and there is a `sno/satellites`result. I'll add it to the question above, as the comment field is limited by the number of characters.

Comment: @bjoern See added code at the end.

Comment: `jq: error: ARGS/0 is not defined at <top-level>, line 2: reduce ($ARGS.named|keys[]) as $key (`
`jq: error: ARGS/0 is not defined at <top-level>, line 4: if $a[$key] < $ARGS.named[$key] then (`
`jq: 2 compile errors`
`(23) Failed writing body`

Comment: @bjoern Are you using an older version of `jq` maybe? I'm on release 1.6 (released November 2018).

Comment: yes, it was 1.5. tried to update from git with https://stackoverflow.com/a/42622937/1625759 and version 1.6, but now jq is broken: `-bash: /usr/bin/jq: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error`. tried with 64 and 32 bit linux version. reinstalled `jq-1.5-1-a5b5cbe` from Debian repo on RPi4.

Comment: I'll update the RPi4 to Debian Bullseye (with jq 1.6) and report the result :)

Comment: Yeah, it's working! :) 2 questions: 1) is it possible to calculate a percentage value of the scores, e.g. 0.99 = 99%, and show it instead of the very long number? 2) how to remove the port `:777`part of the string in the raw-output?

Comment: @bjoern Use `($a.satelliteName | sub(":.*";"")) as $name` instead of just `$a.satelliteName as $name`, then use `\(100*$a[$key]|floor)%` instead of `\($a[$key])`.

Comment: you are my hero. thx a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I‘ve found one possible answer on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70564826/1625759):

```bsh
for sat in `docker exec -i storagenode wget -qO - localhost:14002/api/sno | jq .satellites[].id -r`
do
  docker exec -i storagenode wget -qO - localhost:14002/api/sno/satellite/$sat \
  | jq --raw-output \
    --argjson auditThreshold 1 \
    --argjson suspensionThreshold 1 \
    --argjson onlineThreshold 1 \
    '.audits
      | .satelliteName as $name
      | (
          [{auditScore}, $auditThreshold],
          [{suspensionScore}, $suspensionThreshold],
          [{onlineScore}, $onlineThreshold]
        )
      | select(.[0][] < .[1])
      | "\(.[0] | keys[]) (\(.[0][])) below threshold (\(.[1])) for \($name)"
    '
done
```