# How to make jq output into a variable

Tags: bash, curl, json, jq

here is my code

```bsh
curl random args
"link" | jq
```

and gives it gives is

```json
{
  "id": "961438154596153411",
  "username": "testing",
  "avatar": "a9000496add364b16af27e2f583a2e1e0f",
  "discriminator": "1"
}
```

how would i save that as a bash variables so i could just do like
echo "$id" and it gives me
961438154596153411
or echo "$username"
testing

Solved Note: a better way of doing this is saving the curl input as json and then using that with jq so you dont have to request stuff multiple times
(sorry if this is a dumb question im new to bash and jq)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JSON array to bash variables using jq](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/413878/json-array-to-bash-variables-using-jq)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To extract `961438154596153411` from the json, pipe the file in `jq '.id'`

Example:

```
$ jq '.id' << EOF
{
  "id": "961438154596153411",
  "username": "testing",
  "avatar": "a9000496add364b16af27e2f583a2e1e0f",
  "discriminator": "1"
}
EOF
```

outputs

```
"961438154596153411"
```

If you want it without the quotes, use `-r` for raw data.

All togeather, to put that number into a bash variable, I'd do this:

```
$ id=$(curl random args "link" | jq -r ".id")
$ echo "$id"
961438154596153411
```

Comment: Facing an issue if the value contains space. ex. if the value is `"John Doe"`, I get just `"John`

Comment: @RumitPatel It sounds like you have a missing quotes issue.  `jq '.id' <<< '{"id":"john doe"}'` indeed returns `"john doe"`.  And `jq -r '.id' <<< '{"id":"john doe"}'` returns `john doe`.  That would be a `bash` issue, not a `jq` issue.